# Firebird nbackup delta file

Tags: database, backup, firebird

I want to do a Backup from a Firebird Database. In the documentation I read i should do it with:

```
/opt/firebird/bin/nbackup -B 0 /home/server/daten/DB.fdb DB19082014.nbk
```

This work. I have a file DB19082014.nbk. This I copy to my computer, and now I would Restore it with:

```
/opt/firebird/bin/nbackup -R /home/server/daten/DB.fdb db19082014.nbk
```

But now I get the error:

```
I/O error during "open" operation for file "/home/server/daten/DB.fdb.delta"
Error while trying to open file
null
```

But I don't have a .delta File. Not on my System and not on the System I do the Backup. Knows anybody where or how I can create a empty .delta File? To get the database work?

Thank You

Solution:
The Backup File must be unlocked with:

```
nbackup -F <database>
```

Comment: Which Firebird version do you use?

Comment: In your example you're restoring to same location. Typo or fact?

Comment: Thank You for your help. I found the solution. The Backup must be unlocked with: nbackup -F <database>

Comment: @Burner Good that you found the solution. I would have expected that only to be necessary if the database was locked manually. You might want to consider posting your solution as an answer, and self-accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: The Backup File must be unlocked with:

```
nbackup -F <database>
```